# Endomorphim Ring of Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory

In the paper

"Über die Abelschen Gruppen mit nullteilerfreiem Endomorphismenring."

Szele considers the problem of describing all abelian groups with endomorphism ring contaning no zero-divisors. He proved that there is no such group among the mixed groups. While $C(p)$ and $C(p^\infty)$ are the only torsion groups of this property.

I do not have access to this paper. Moreover, I do not speak German, someone can give me a reference, in English or French, for this result or Sketch the Proof?

Comment: This seems to be a very nice example where one :(1) needs to go and dive into one's mathematics dept's library and search for all journals' papers, and (2) needs to begin to learn a basic german in order to translate a paper which very probably has no translation into english. Don't worry, many of us had to do that...

Comment: I tried to find the result in Fuchs' book, but I didn't find it, although the paper is cited.

Comment: @egreg: Cor 27.4 vol1 is Kulikov's result. Szele's result should have been mentioned in exercise 7 on page 238 of vol 2. Theorem 111.1 is a related result of Szele, and the proof is the same as the one I give below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kulikov proved that an indecomposable abelian group is either torsion-free or $C(p^k)$ for some $k=0,1,\dots,\infty$. A direct summand creates a zero divisor in the endomorphism ring: Let $G = A \oplus B$ and define $e(a,b) = (a,0)$. Then $e^2=e$ and $e(1-e) = 0$. However $1-e$ is the endomorphism that takes $(a,b)$ to $(0,b)$ so it is not zero either.